# Logically splitting a linear array into two circular arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Let me come up with a example.
I have an array of people (say of size 10).
Men can occupy indices 0 to 4 and women can occupy indices 5 to 9.
How do I make sure that the second half of the array (for women) is a circular array. How do I do add to this.

Normally, for circular I would do:

```
index = index % size;
people[index] = person;
```

How do I make sure that the array is circular in each half separately?

Comment: why you are preferring single array instead of two separate array for woman and man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an addition based on the size of the array. If you don't know the exact size but you know the proportion you can do some math to get it.

For example if there are x number of people in the array and half the array is for men and half for women you would do something like this:

```
menIndex = index % (array.length - (array.length / 2));
womenIndex = (index % array.length) + (array.length / 2);
```

The `menIndex` checks if the index is past the halfway point of the entire array.
The `womenIndex` checks if the index reached the end of the array and then adds value of half the array to bring it back to the beginning of its half of the array

You really should just use 2 separate arrays if you can though as rupesh commented above.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thank you very much.